# Is there a per-connected-time (and per-storage-time) billed PostgreSQL server available in an european cloud?

Tags: azure, postgresql, cloud

A friend running a business with currently roughly 30 (somewhat elastic) employees asked me to make an existing personal/ desktop database available to his remote and somewhat distributed employees with some additional functionality and for sure access restrictions.

The additional functionality he needs, I did nearly exactly some time ago in another project and is depending on the database being Postgres.

The former project I was running shared with others on my own virtual server, which is not an option for me now and also has the drawback that it has no containers, which I learned to love for maintenance.

A dedicated server costs me a lot of money, due to the required peak disk space of 2TB every now and then (can be daily, but usually monthly) and else only requiring less than 100GB.
Also there is a peak load expectation roughly four times a day and else the load is nearly zero.

I already took a look at the Azure Germany cloud (to make it feasible to comply with European privacy law) and, because the PostgreSQL database is apparently not paid  per connection-time, but per up-time, the whole thing is much more expensive than even a dedicated server.

Can anyone recommend a solution?

A web-hosting with PostgreSQL database will probably not work, because I have to install extensions to PostgreSQL (except they would be already there by luck) and I would prefer to have control over when the Postgres (and node.js) version changes.

Comment: You can get a dedicated server with more than 2TB of storage for €100 per month or less. Including VAT. Do some shopping. Maybe check Hetzner's server auctions.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I know, this was about a possible alternative with a cloud based solution.

Comment: I was about to ask *Why does postgresql DBaaS not scale? / Why is nobody offering postgresql at the price of replication count x peak hardware?* and I suspect it boils down to the same thing.